# gcc shared library with header in the same library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile a shared library (.so) with the following code:
libreceive.h:

```
#include <stddef.h>
int receive(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

libreceive.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <libreceive/libreceive.h>

int receive(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags){
    return recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags);
}
```

the problem here is that I'm trying to include the .h in the library that I'm building and using it in the same time from the same library in the .c .
I know that what I'm trying to do is possible, but I can't manage to do it.
How can I do that please.

the code I'm trying is:

```
gcc -o libreceive.o -c -include libreceive.h libreceive.c
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: libreceive/libreceive.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

the problem here is that I'm trying to include the .h in the library that I'm building and using it in the same time from the same library in the .c .
I know that what I'm trying to do is possible, but I can't manage to do it.
How can I do that please.

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -o libreceive.o -c libreceive.c -I /Path/to/include` ?, considering your `libreceive.h` is in directory `include`.

Comment: libreceive is the library I'm trying to compile

Comment: In that case, you have to use `-shared` or `-fPIC` option with gcc, No mention of that ?

Comment: I tried this also this:
gcc -shared -o libreceive.so -fPIC libreceive.c  in a lot of variants, no luck...

Comment: @user1928596 If `libreceive.c` is in the same folder as `libreceive.h`, you can use `#include "libreceive.h"` in `libreceive.c`. In any other project that wants to use libreceive, you use `#include <libreceive/libreceive.h>` together with the compiler flag `-I/path/to` , where /path/to contains a libreceive folder, (meaning the full path to `libreceive.h` is `/path/to/libreceive/libreceive.h`)

Answer (score 1):

Since `libreceive.h` and `libreceive.c` appear to be in the same directory (judging from your compiler call), the normal way is

```
#include "libreceive.h"
```

In order to use

```
#include <libreceive/libreceive.h>
```

`libreceive.h` would have to lie in a directory called `libreceive`, and that directory would have to be part of the include path. It is possible to achieve this, but I believe it is neither necessary nor useful here.

Comment: I'm using it else where, when importing, and for the second part of your answer the .h shouldn't be on another folder on the path, I't should be put before in the same library

Comment: @user1928596 whether you are using it elsewhere has nothing to do with how you are using it in libreceive.c.

Comment: You don't have to use the same `#include` directive when using the library in another project. You can use `#include "libreceive.h"` in the library itself, where the header lies in the same directory, and use `#include <libreceive/libreceive.h>` in client code that pulls in the header from some directory `libreceive` in its include path.

Comment: I this manage to make ot woth like in the comment of previous response

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out a few steps here.
Consider the following setup.

File: `add.c`

```
#include "header.h"
int add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("SIZE: %d\n", SIZE);
    return a+b;
}
```

File: `sub.c`

```
#include "header.h"
int sub(int a, int b)
{
    printf("SIZE: %d\n", SIZE);
    return a-b;
}
```

File: `header.h`, located in directory called `include`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
```

So to step by step build a `.so` file.

```
/* Build `.o` files first */
$ gcc -fPIC -c sub.c -I path/to/include/
$ gcc -fPIC -c add.c -I path/to/include/

/* Build shared library called libsample.so */
$ gcc -shared -o libsample.so add.o sub.o
```

The above command will build a `.so` by name `libsample.so`.
Where all definition from `.c`(like functions) and `.h`(like `#define`s) will get included in your library.

---

**How to use this in your code:**

Consider the file
File: `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    printf("Return : %d\n", add(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

To make use of your library `libsample.so`.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/direc/containing/.so/file
$ gcc -o exe main.c -lsample -L/path/to/direc/containing/.so/file
```

The above command should create a binary called `exe`.

```
$./exe
SIZE : 100              /* SIZE Defined in .h file */
Return : 7              /* Defined in add.c */
```

You can refer this guide : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: I tried you code, but when I'm doing that and It indeed compiles,
when I use this lib in another classgcc -o test test.c -lreceive it don't work (I put the library in the path)

Comment: thank you, I found the probleme else where, any way both techniques work now, so I'll up vote a and write my answer for where I hace the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I decided to use `#include "libreceive.h"` as suggested by the guys. the probleme I had is that the compiler was looking for my so in /usr/lib wich is the default when id do sudo gcc and my usr had the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH at /usr/local/lib and therefore gcc coudn't find my library at compile time
another problem was that the program that call thos .so  was looking fro the .h in some folder that doesn't exist and I had to add it.
thanks guys for you answers